# Rewrite scope to use ActiveRecord helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following scope inside my model:

```
  scope :by_attributes, ->(names) {
    attribute_ids = ReferralPartnerAttribute.where(name: names).pluck(:id)
    if attribute_ids.any?
      where(
        "ARRAY[?] <@ (
          SELECT array_agg(referral_partner_attribute_id)
          FROM referral_partner_referral_partner_attributes
          WHERE referral_partner_referral_partner_attributes.referral_partner_id = referral_partners.id)", attribute_ids
      )
    else
      none
    end
  }
```

How can I rewrote it in more ActiveRecor way? Is this possible?

Comment: Can you share what associations exist between the tables used here? Also, I'm not sure this does what you think it does. It sounds like you want referral_partners that have referral_partner_attributes with matching names. But I believe this will return *all* referral_partners if you pass any attribute that exists.

Answer (score 1):

How about calling another scope inside scope?

```
scope :by_attributes, ->(names) { (attribute_ids = ReferralPartnerAttribute.where(name: names).pluck(:id)).present? ? another_scope(attribute_ids) : none }
scope :another_scope, ->(attribute_ids) { where("ARRAY[?] <@ (
        SELECT array_agg(referral_partner_attribute_id)
        FROM referral_partner_referral_partner_attributes
        WHERE referral_partner_referral_partner_attributes.referral_partner_id = referral_partners.id)", attribute_ids
      )}
```

Doing this will also help calling this scope directly if you already have `attribute_ids` in hand and don't need to check if it is empty or not..

Comment: Is there any way to rewrite this raw sql with some ActiveRecord helpers?

Comment: not much familiar with `jsonb` but still I doubt it can be simplified as it is an aggregated query which is not very well supported by `AR`, however, not sure if you can replace `FROM referral_partner_referral_partner_attributes WHERE referral_partner_referral_partner_attributes.referral_partner_id = referral_partners.id` with `joins()`